# Show jlabel when select an item in jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

I have a jframe that has a jcmbobox with three state (three item, from 0 to 2).

i want when user select second item(1) my jlabel should be display!

But now, when i select second item,  Don't show it!

```
public class LoginFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public LoginFrame() {
    initComponents();
    this.setTitle("Library Management System Login");
    this.setLocation(300, 50);
    this.setResizable(false);
    if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        jLabel4.setVisible(true);
    }
    else{
        jLabel4.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

My selected index number in my IDE menu is 0.

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code in the constructor will not reflect changes made to the selected item in the `JComboBox`. You need to use a `Listener` such as an `ActionListener` to detect these changes:

```
jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       jLabel4.setVisible(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() == 1);
    }
});
```

Aside: A slight improvement can be made by making the statement use the comparison expression directly in the `setVisible` statement as shown.

See [Handling Events on a Combo Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ActionListener` to do this:

```
jComboBox1.addActionListener(this);
...
jLabel4.setVisible(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() == 1);
```